# PySide QPainter.drawRect() with QBrush offset issue

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm trying to draw my custom push button which has dimensions 20x20 pixels. I created a class that inherits QPushButton and I have overwritten paintEvent method with this code below:

```
painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)

x = self.rect().x()
y = self.rect().y()

width = self.rect().width()
height = self.rect().height()

painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(170, 97, 112)))
painter.drawRect(x, y, width, height)
```

And this is what I get (edited in Photoshop):

[image]

You can clearly see 1 pixel offset both in x, and y dimensions on the top left.

I was wondering why this is happening. I can get rid of this by extracting 1 pixel from x, and y and adding 1 pixel to width and height, so their value will be: x = -1; y = -1; width = 21; height = 21.

But this just feels wierd to me. I don't know if this is an issue with Qt (or maybe just PySide) or I don't understand something.

Comment: You state that your custom push button is 20x20 in size yet the image above shows a rectangle 22x22.  So what part of the image above is actually *your* push button?

Comment: @G.M. No, it's actually 20x20. I marked the button with a red brush (from 0 to 20). The image itself is just cropped like this. Sorry if this is confusing in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your getting confused about what `QPainter::drawRect` actually does.  From the [QPainter documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawRect-2)

> Draws the current rectangle with the current pen and brush.

The rectangle is filled with the current brush and outlined with the current pen.  With that in mind I suspect that when you call `QPainter::drawRect` you have a pen active for the painter causing the grey outline you see.

If all you want is to fill the rectangle then you can use...

```
painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
painter.fillRect(this->rect(), QBrush(QColor(170, 97, 112)))
```

Comment: Yeah so it turns out I have to declare "clear pen" `QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0), 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)` and give it to QPainter, otherwise if I don't set any pen for QPainter it will use it's own default (gray 1px solid).

Comment: @Makal Are you aware of the null pen? Perhaps that's what you want if you want no pen.

Comment: @KubaOber Well, I never have heared of the term "null pen" but if you mean QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen) then yea I already swap this line with my previous "clear pen" - works the same, just shorter.